# Issue when create a user on Azure B2C using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

**Issue**

I'm trying to build a little script PHP to integrate with the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).

I have an admin account in Azure, and have set up a new app through the portal. I've downloaded and installed the [PHP SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php), and have managed to set everything up so that I can get a user successfully.

However, POSTing a new user returns me a 400 bad request:

```
$newUser = new User();
$newUser->setAccountEnabled(true);
$newUser->setGivenName('name');
$newUser->setSurname('surname');
$newUser->setUserPrincipalName('email@dot.com');

$password = new PasswordProfile();
$password->setPassword("pwd");
$password->setForceChangePasswordNextSignIn(false);
$newUser->setPasswordProfile($password);

$identities = new ObjectIdentity();
$identities->setSignInType("emailAddress");
$identities->setIssuer("a tenantId");
$identities->setIssuerAssignedId("email@dot.com");
$newUser->setIdentities($identities);

$user = $this->graph->createRequest('POST', '/users')
        ->attachBody($newUser)
        ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
        ->execute();
```

Returns:

```
{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Property identities in payload has a value that does not match schema.","innerError":{"date":"2021-11-15T15:26:24","request-id":"an id","client-request-id":"an id"}}}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks for any help.

**Update**

I have found a solution for this problem (obviously, is temporary).

The section "identities" must be set as an array (in JSON) like in this example

```
"identities": [
{
  "signInType": "emailAddress",
  "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
  "issuerAssignedId": "jsmith@yahoo.com"
}
]
```

Probably, the PHP code above not set the section "identities" as an array.

Now, I send directly a JSON with the section "identities" as an array but I would like to use the PHP code above.

How can I transform the PHP code above to pass "identities" as an array like in the JSON example?

Thanks again.

Comment: Can you try with $identities->setIssuer("tenant domain name"); instead of tenant id

Comment: Hello @RamaraoAdapa-MT. Thanks for your response. I have found the solution. The section "identities" must be treast as an array in JSON. Probably, my code don't set the section "identities" like an array.

Comment: Can you try this code to set identities as an array: $identity1 = new ObjectIdentity();
$identity1->setSignInType("emailAddress");
$identity1->setIssuer("a tenantId");
$identity1->setIssuerAssignedId("email@dot.com");
$identities = array($identity1);
$newUser->setIdentities($identities);

Comment: Hello @RamaraoAdapa-MT. Thanks again for this response. I'll try your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an array and adding the identities on there like. This will add the identities property as an array of Model\ObjectIdentity()

```
 ...
 $identities = [];

 $identity = new Model\ObjectIdentity();
 $identity->setSignInType("type");
 $identity->setIssuer("issuer");
 $identity->setIssuerAssignedId("issure-assigned-id");

 array_push($identities, $identity);

 $newUser->setIdentities($identities);
 ...
```